# Ligature for the nt digraph

Tags: characters, ligatures

I want to draw in LaTeX a ligature for the nt digraph.
I would prefer a solution that is independent from the font used. But if it is not possible, the default one (CM) will do.

I currently use `\newcommand\nt{n\!t}` but it is ugly.

I am not sure what the glyph should look like but here's a vague idea (the n is not really looking as an n but I am a poor drawer):

[image: nt]

As an example, st is ligatured as ﬆ.

**Edit.** Another option would be the following ([historically attested](https://lichfield.ou.edu/st-chad-gospels/hands))

[image: unt]

[image: nt2]

Comment: A ligature is a special glyph in a given font, so I don't see, how you can have a font independent solution

Comment: It would help to know what context this is to be used in.  Is it specific to a particular language?

Comment: This ligature can be found in some Latin manuscripts (with a different glyph though).

Comment: With the tipa package `\textrtailn\kern-.25em-` is near to the second option, but certainly ugly.

Comment: With XeTeX or LuaTeX and a font supporting extended Latin characters, `\char"0273\kern.05em\raise.15em\hbox{\char"0320}` gives a roughly similar result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMHO, this  macro `\nt` works nice with both upright and italics fonts in 10-12pt  CM, but obviously will need some adjustments using another font or different font sizes:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nt}{%
\def\statusem{it}%
\ifx\f@shape\statusem%
n\kern-.105em\raisebox{-0.25em}{t}\else
n\kern-0.27em\raisebox{-0.4em}{t}\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
    audiunt audiu\nt \par\em 
    audiunt audiu\nt
\end{document}
```

As commented, a general solution is impossible, but having an already made general digraph could work well *in some cases* without adjustments  saving the digraph alone in a pdf,  and the using the pdf as an image, of course, with a relative size (i.e., with the width in em).

For the italics you cannot make the same kind of joining because the "n" tail is already a broken ligature and you must use it as connect point for best results.

The example above show join the "t" at the left extreme of the horizontal bar, but another reasonable options could be point to the middle of this bar, to simulate and ascending trace to the top of the "t", or from the bottom, without descending the second character in this case:

[image: mwe2]

```
\nt\quad  n\kern-.16em\raisebox{-0.25em}{t}\quad n\kern-.13em t
```

For my taste the horizontal bar is too near to the "n" in the second and third version, although the third have the advantage of look more conventional. Anyway, what is better is up to you.

But another possibility is not make the ligature with "n", but with the default  `\eta`, that have not right tail:

[image: mwe]

```
audiu$\eta$\kern-.365em\raisebox{-0.4em}{t}
```

Comment: The upright version is awesome (I wonder how you found the -.105 value)! I am a little more sceptical about italics but I imagine your proposal will do the trick. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Blincer I edited the answer to add other options for the italics.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time spent on improving the italics, I haven't made my choice yet but it will definitely be one of those, thank you.

Comment: @Blincer. Maybe not one of these. I added  one more equivalent to the  upright version.